# Please help me identify this 1927 flooring found under carpet? I need to buy 30 feet for repairs

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

I’d love to learn how to identify type and color so I can buy some matching repair pieces

[image]
[image]

Comment: It can't be just sanded and refinished?   The damage doesn't look too deep.

Comment: I bet they need to fill in a hole.

Comment: Yep! Need to fill a huge space near a wall where there’s just subfloor

Comment: Identifying wood from a picture is tough enough that it's off-topic at [woodworking.se]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like vertical grain Douglas Fir to me.